# Defining a statsmodels state space representation for an observation matrix that depends on both observed and unobserved variables

Tags: python, statsmodels, kalman-filter, state-space

I am modeling a time series using a Kalman filter in the Python statsmodels package (Python 3.9 and statsmodels 0.13).  The state space transition matrix looks like this:

[image: transition matrix]

The observation matrix looks like this (note that it depends on both the unobserved variable v *as well as past values of the two observed variables p and n*):

[image: observation matrix]

How might I define this kind of state space equation as a statsmodel MLEModel?  I can capture most of this model through:

```
class AR1(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    start_params = [-0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05]  # best guess at initial params
    param_names = ['-psi', '1-phi', 'r_t', 'e_t', 'w_t']
    
    def __init__(self, endog):
        # Initialize the state space model
        super(AR1, self).__init__(endog, k_states=2, k_posdef=1,
                                     initialization='stationary')

        # Setup the fixed components of the state space representation
        self['design'] = [[1., 1.],
                          [1., 0]]
        self['transition'] = [[1., 0],
                              [1., 0]]
        self['selection', 0, 0] = 1.

    # Describe how parameters enter the model
    def update(self, params, transformed=True, **kwargs):
        params = super(AR1, self).update(params, transformed, **kwargs)

        self['design', 0, 1] = params[0]        # param.0 is -psi
        self['design', 1, 0] = params[1]        # param.1 is (1-phi)
        self['selection', 0, 0] = params[2]     # param.2 is r_t  
        self['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[3]       # param.3 is e_t
        self['obs_cov', 1, 1] = params[4]       # param.4 is w_t

    # Specify start parameters and parameter names
    @property
    def start_params(self):
        return self.start_params

# Create and fit the model
mod = AR1(DepVars)

# Display results
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
res.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(13,7))
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to add the first term of the observation equation, which depends on both psi/phi as well as the prior observations themselves.  Is there something I am missing?  Perhaps by considering that term as an intercept somehow?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're exactly right, these can be included in the observation intercept term. Here's how I would write this model:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace import tools


class SSM(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    # If you use _param_names and _start_params then the model
    # will automatically pick them up
    _param_names = ['phi', 'psi', 'sigma2_r', 'sigma2_e', 'sigma2_w']
    _start_params = [0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 1, 1]

    def __init__(self, endog):
        # Extract lagged endog
        X = sm.tsa.lagmat(endog, maxlag=1, trim='both', original='in')
        endog = X[:, :2]
        self.lagged_endog = X[:, 2:]

        # Initialize the state space model
        # Note: because your state process is nonstationary,
        # you can't use stationary initialization
        super().__init__(endog, k_states=2, k_posdef=1,
                         initialization='diffuse')

        # Setup the fixed components of the state space representation
        self['design'] = [[1., 1.],
                          [1., 0]]
        self['transition'] = [[1., 0],
                              [1., 0]]
        self['selection'] = [[1],
                             [0]]

    # For the parameter estimation part, it is
    # helpful to use parameter transformations to
    # keep the parameters in the valid domain. Here
    # I assumed that you wanted phi and psi to be
    # between (-1, 1).
    def transform_params(self, params):
        params = params.copy()
        for i in range(2):
            params[i:i + 1] = tools.constrain_stationary_univariate(params[i:i + 1])
        params[2:] = params[2:]**2
        return params
    
    def untransform_params(self, params):
        params = params.copy()
        for i in range(2):
            params[i:i + 1] = tools.unconstrain_stationary_univariate(params[i:i + 1])
        params[2:] = params[2:]**0.5
        return params

    # Describe how parameters enter the model
    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)

        # Here is where we're putting the lagged endog, multiplied
        # by phi and psi into the intercept term
        self['obs_intercept'] = self.lagged_endog.T * params[:2, None]
        self['design', 0, 1] = -params[0]
        self['design', 1, 0] = 1 - params[1]
        self['state_cov', 0, 0] = params[2]
        self['obs_cov'] = np.diag(params[3:5])
```

And we can simulate some data and then run the fitting routine to check if it seems to be working correctly:

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(12345)

# Specify some parameters to simulate data and
# check the model
nobs = 5000
params = np.r_[0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 1.5, 2.5]

# Simulate data
v = rs.normal(scale=params[2]**0.5, size=nobs + 1).cumsum()
e = rs.normal(scale=params[3]**0.5, size=nobs + 1)
w = rs.normal(scale=params[4]**0.5, size=nobs + 1)

p = np.zeros(nobs + 1)
n = np.zeros(nobs + 1)

for t in range(1, nobs):
    p[t] = params[0] * p[t - 1] + v[t] - params[0] * v[t - 1] + e[t]
    n[t] = params[1] * n[t - 1] + (1 - params[1]) * v[t] + w[t]
    
y = np.c_[p, n]

# Run MLE routine on the fitted data
mod = SSM(y)
res = mod.fit(disp=False)

# Check the estimated parameters
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame({
    'True': params,
    'Estimated': res.params
}, index=mod.param_names).round(2))
```

shows me:

```
          True  Estimated
phi        0.2       0.17
psi        0.8       0.81
sigma2_r   0.1       0.09
sigma2_e   1.5       1.49
sigma2_w   2.5       2.47
```

Comment: So powerful.  This works very well for my purposes.  Thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to add a drift term to r, e, and w, such that I was modeling a time series like rs.normal(loc=params[5], scale=params[2]**0.5, size=nobs+1), could I accomplish that by adding params to the intercept matrices?

Comment: Yes, that's the most straightforward way to add a deterministic term.

Answer (score 0):

For the proposed answer, it seems that it no longer works when I set some values to nan in the data. I'm puzzled about which step requires the completeness of data.

update: i realise it's because the RHS lags can't have any missing values, but how should we deal with the case when there are some inherent missing values in the data?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35743613)